# Eigenvalues of convolution matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $h: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Fix $0\leq s_1\leq \cdots \leq s_m\leq 1$ and $0\leq t_1\leq \cdots \leq t_n\leq 1$. Construct $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ by letting $A_{i,j}:=h(s_i-t_j)$. What can we say about the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and their decay rate? Assuming reasonable conditions on $s_i,t_j$.

Comment: Qualitatively, nothing: generically the $s_i-t_j$ will be distinct so by interpolation one can fit a smooth function $h$ to match any given choice of $A_{ij}$.  Quantitatively: if one has bounds on smooth norms on $h$ then one can expand $h$ as a Fourier integral (or Fourier series on $[-1,1]$ or some slight enlargement thereof) to express $A$ or $A^T A$ as the rapidly decreasing sum of rank 1 matrices which can lead to various spectral or singular value bounds e.g., in the nuclear norm (or even Schatten $p$ norms for some $p<1$).